# How to FindControl() in a GridView while in Edit mode?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, findcontrol

I want to access controls and update database with their value. Notice using following code:

```
void grdList_UpdateCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
        string str = ((RadTextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtLookupItemValue")).Text;
}
```

I have access to control txtLookupItemValue, but it contains before-edit content, not actual value that user has entered.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried setting the string during the edit event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

   string str = ((RadTextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtLookupItemValue")).Text;

}
```

Then update your DB and rebind the gridview to display the updated row.

Comment: I have tested value of `str1` in debug mode. It just contains before-edit-value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the value when the grid is updating.  E.g:

```
protected void GridUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
string str = (RadTextBox)this.yourGridviewName.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtLookupItemValue").Text;
}
```

Then add this to the gridview on the aspx:

```
OnRowUpdating="GridUpdating"
```

Comment: I'm using Telerik's RadGrid. It does not have any event named Updating.